# Why is the java method Provider.getService(String type, String algorithm) synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption, synchronized, jce

Many Java libraries are relying on the [Provider.getService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html#getService-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method, for example MessageDigest, Cipher and many others. When a web server needs hash or encryption as a part of its business flow it uses the Java Security library which eventually calls to the method:

```
 public synchronized Service getService(String type, String algorithm)
```

In a multi-threaded server after certain load, many threads are starting to compete for the lock on the above method, which leads to very serious bottleneck affecting the throughput of the server.

We solve this issue by adding Aspect which intercepts methods that eventually call to Provider.getService and cache the instances of these objects in a ThreadLocal.

Could someone explain please, why in first place the developers of the Provider.getService decided to put 'synchronized' on that method?? Why they could not solve the race condition by using ConcurrentMap?

Comment: @Gray - true enough.  guess i missed that.  The Provider class is pretty old, but the Service methods seem to be from 1.5.

Comment: @Romande, can you please share your Aspect? I'm running into the same problem and I have no idea on how to solve it :-\

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone explain please, why in first place the developers of the Provider.getService decided to put 'synchronized' on that method?? Why they could not solve the race condition by using ConcurrentMap?

The `Provider.getService(...)` method says available since 1.5 so `ConcurrentHashMap` was written when this the `getService(...)` code was.  If you look at the code, the call is doing more than executing map operations.  For example:

```
    // avoid allocating a new key object if possible
    ServiceKey key = previousKey;
    if (key.matches(type, algorithm) == false) {
        key = new ServiceKey(type, algorithm, false);
        previousKey = key;
    }
```

This sort of get/test/set operation isn't handled by `ConcurrentHashMap` unless you create the key ahead of time which the programmers might have thought was computationally excessive.

It may also be that they expected folks to do exactly what you are doing which is to create and then cache the instance of the service.  Certainly putting these in `ThreadLocal`s is what I've been doing.

Hope this helps.